# How to load classes in an eclipse plug-in

Tags: class, eclipse-plugin, classloader

I want to load a class such as database driver from the user's workspace within my eclipse plug-in. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can add a project as a resource to another in Eclipse, then you just import through the package hierarchy as usual.